# Use 'active' state from React Router in Styled Components

Tags: react-router, styled-components

React Router adds an `active` class to NavLinks when you are on the page that they link to. How can I access this property with Styled Components. I need to styled menu items differently when you are on their page.

```
const LinkElem = styled(NavLink)`
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;

  ${props => console.log(props)};

  &:hover {
    color: ${props => props.theme.colorOrange};
  }
`;

const Menu = props => {
  const { me } = props;
  return (
    <MenuElem>
      <li>
        {me ? (
          <LinkElem to="/account">Account</LinkElem>
        ) : (
          <LinkElem to="/login">Log in / sign up</LinkElem>
        )}
      </li>
    </MenuElem>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not particularly keen on the `&.active` approach if you're trying to build a styled-component that is router independent, so I created [`asNavLink`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/as-nav-link) to deal with this:

`npm install as-nav-link --save`

Given a component:

```
const MyNavAnchor = styled(({
  as: T = 'a',
  active, // destructured so it is not passed to anchor in props
  ...props
}) => <T {...props} />)({
  textDecoration: 'blink',
  color: 'blue',
}, ({ active }) => (active && {
  color: 'red',
}));
```

You can use it like this:

```
 import asNavLink from 'as-nav-link';

 const MyNavLink = asNavLink(config)(MyNavAnchor);
```

And it will pass down the active prop to your styled component.

`config` is optional and can include an `isActive` function (as per ReactRouter's NavLink) and an `activeProp` string (the prop name that is passed to your component).

Answer (score 28):

The prop className is getting added to the children of NavLink and so its not accessible at NavLink level. The [docs](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/docs/api/NavLink.md) were not clear about this. Therefore, we cannot check for props.className === 'active' and add styles.

Instead, you could just resort to css inside styled components for your use:

```
  const LinkElem = styled(NavLink)`
  // example style
  &.active {
    color: ${props => props.theme.orange }
  }
`;
```

Comment: I know about NavLink but I'm using Styled Components: https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components

Comment: @Evans ok.. i think i misunderstood your ques.. I have edited my answer.. See if this is what your looking for

Comment: I don't have that prop. Have you got this working yourself or did you assume that it would be passed? Thanks

Comment: @Evans I referred the docs and it said "The default given class is active. This will be joined with the className prop.". But after investigating, I find that the className prop is not passed to this NavLink component but to its children ( <Link>, <a>). So, that is why it is not accessible for you.

Comment: Easiest solution so far

Answer (score 10):

As of `react-router` v4, you can style the active state of `NavLink` without any dependencies using `activeClassName` and Styled Components' `attrs()` function:

```
export const StyledNavLink = styled(NavLink).attrs({
  activeClassName,
})`

  &.${activeClassName} {
    background: red;
  }
`;
```

Related documentation:

- [`activeClassName`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/NavLink/activeclassname-string)
- [`attrs()`](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/api#attrs)

Answer (score 5):

```
const StyledLink = styled(NavLink)`
  color: blue;

  &.active {
    color: red;
  }
`;
```

Answer (score 1):

**If you are using object syntax in styled-components, you can implement the next solution:**

```
const activeClassName = 'nav-item-active'

export const StyledLink = styled(NavLink).attrs({
    activeClassName,
})(props => ({
    height: '20px',
    width: '20px',
    backgroundColor: 'green',
    ['&.' + props.activeClassName]: {
        backgroundColor: 'red'
    }
}))
```

- Declare variable with the name of the active class of react router
- Style the NavLink and pass as attribute activeClassName
- From the props get the activeClassName
- Declare the conditional styles in case of the activeClassName being present

**You can check a live example in the next StackBlitz project:**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-hcudxz

Answer (score 1):

Styled component:

```
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';

export const MyNavLink = styled(NavLink)`
  &.${props => props.activeClassName} {
    color: red;
  }
`;
```

Usage:

```
<MyNavLink to="/dashboard" activeClassName="anyClassNameWillWork">Dashboard</MyNavLink>
```

Tested with:

**react-router-dom 5.1.2**
**styled-components 5.0.1**

Answer (score 1):

The string you added to NavLink's `activeClassName` will join to `className` later when you hit the specific route. Since styled components support pure css,

```
&.{yourActiveClassName} { #css goes here}
```

should work.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's simplest decision.

```
const StyledLink = styled(NavLink)`
  color: blue;

  &.${props => props.activeClassName} {
    color: red;
  }
`;
```

Answer (score 0):

react-router now has `activeStyle` props, which can be used to style active link easily:

```
<NavLink
  to="/faq"
  activeStyle={{
    fontWeight: "bold",
    color: "red"
  }}
>
  FAQs
</NavLink>
```

With styled-components:

```
const LinkElem = styled(NavLink)`
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
`;

<LinkElem
  activeStyle={{
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    color: 'red',
  }}
></LinkElem>;
```

Comment: This no longer works in v6 https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/upgrading/v5#remove-activeclassname-and-activestyle-props-from-navlink-