# Why isn't React-Scroll activeClass not working?

Tags: reactjs

I am using React-scroll for the scroll effect and everything works fine as far as the scrolling to my specific section, but for some reason the activeClass part from the docs isn't working.

Here is my Link code

```
             <Link
                to='about'
                smooth={true}
                duration={1000}
                activeClass='active'
              >
                HEY
              </Link>
```

Then my active CSS

```
.active {
 color: red;
}
```

Am I missing something?

For styled components how would I implement the activeClass?

```
    const Navbar = ({ toggle, active }) => {
      return (

        <NavLinks
              to='about'
              smooth={true}
              duration={1000}
              activeClass={active}
              spy={true}
            >
              About
            </NavLinks>


       export const NavLinks = styled(Link)`
        border-bottom: ${({ active }) =>
          active ? '3px solid blue' : '5px solid red'};
      `;
```

I figured out a way, but not sure if it's the best method

```
     <NavLinks
              to='about'
              smooth={true}
              duration={1000}
              activeClass={active ? 'active' : ''}
              spy={true}
            >
              About
            </NavLinks>
```

Then in a separate css file I just added

```
 a.active {
 color: red;
 }
```

if you don't put a. before the active class, then it will only receive the color of the text from your original styled component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Link to documentation https://styled-components.com/docs/basics#pseudoelements-pseudoselectors-and-nesting

```
const NavLinks = styled(Link)`
  color: blue;
  &.active {
    color: red;
  }
`;
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to set `spy={true}` so that the Link will be selected when scroll is at its targets position

```
<Link
  to='about'
  smooth={true}
  duration={1000}
  activeClass='active'
  spy={true}
>
  HEY
</Link>
```

Comment: I have styled components too, how would I update the class? I added my code above, but couldn't get it to work

Answer (score 0):

**Link** no longer has *activeClass* you have to use ***NavLink*** instead

```
<BrowserRouter>
<div>
  <Nav>
    <NavLink exact={true} activeClassName='is-active' to='/about'>About</NavLink>
  </Nav>

  <Match pattern='/about' exactly component={About} />
  <Miss component={NoMatch} />
</div>
```

Comment: wdym it no longer works? also do you know how to implement it with styled components? I updated my code above

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52897336/14312493 try this

Comment: the issue is I am using `react-scroll` so I have to `import {Link} from 'react-scroll` so NavLink doesn't exist in that package.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass spy as `props` to your NavLink component instead of Link component.
Example:

```
<NavLink spy smooth>HEY</Link>
```

Comment: How would I do that with styled components?

Comment: can you make a forked link on sandbox or stackblitz? That would be easier to solve for me.
Or else:
Try using activeClassName, isActive, activeStyle as props in there.

Comment: I just tested the regular Link tag with an active class works fine, but I just don't know how to refactor my styled component to use the activeClass.

Comment: see my above comment, I have edited it
You may refer this doc once: https://reactrouter.com/web/api/NavLink

Comment: I used `activeClass={active ? 'active' : ''}` and in the console it's adding an active class to it, but I need it to only get the style from the styled component not add a literally `active` class. Also where did you get those props? I don't see those on the react-scroll docs

Comment: Those props are not from react-scroll docs, they are from NavLink (router concept) you can find it there or link I have pasted.
As you were saying you need to get the style from the styled component, can you show that styled component what props are been passed there?
If I understand you correctly.

Comment: EDIT: It says I can't import NavLink from react-scroll. I just created a active prop that should show a border-bottom if the link is active. I'll look into the react router doc you sent, cause I think isActive might help me, but idk yet

Comment: Also if this helps: https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/issues/184

Answer (score 0):

If you want to style the active class with a styled-component, use the [.attrs](https://styled-components.com/docs/api#attrs) to set the active class name prop, then use the class name in the CSS. Note on the `&`, you may have to play around with it to increase the selector specificity if it classes with any existing styling/classes/etc. By setting the `activeClass` prop directly on the component you don't have to specify the classname when consuming the link in your UI code.

```
export const NavLinks = styled(Link).attrs(() => ({
  activeClass: 'active',
}))`
  // non-active styles
  border-bottom: 5px solid red;

  &.active {
    // active styles
    border-bottom: 3px solid blue;
  }
`;
```

Answer (score 0):

i was struggling with the active class dissapearing after a few milliseconds. The problem was my tab was zoomed out to 90%. Zooming back to 100% with ctrl+scroll fixed my problem :^)