# How to make activeClass on NavLink - styled component

Tags: reactjs, react-router, styled-components

Hi everyone im in trouble with active Link, i use Styled Component.
I want my link to be Red when i'm on active link but nothing work.
I tried ActiveCLassName but this not work too.

can someone help me?

thanks a lot

```
const NavLink = styled(Link)`
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
height: 100%;
padding: 0 10px;
list-style-type: none;
text-decoration: none;
color: black;
background-color: yellow;
border: 0.1px solid lightgrey;
`;

export default function Nav() {
  return (
<NavWrapper>
  <UlNav>
    <LiNav>
      <NavLink to="/Burgers">Burgers</NavLink>
    </LiNav>
    <LiNav>
      <NavLink to="/Burgers">Pizza</NavLink>
    </LiNav>
    <LiNav>
      <NavLink to="/Burgers">Drinks</NavLink>
    </LiNav>
  </UlNav>
</NavWrapper>
)};
```

Answer (score 5):

## Issues

The issue I see is you are styling the `Link` component instead of the `NavLink` component. The `Link` component doesn't take any additional props for handling active links.

## Solution

The `NavLink` component uses a `.active` class by default, so of you don't need any special classname you should use this class.

Example:

```
import { NavLink as BaseNavLink } from "react-router-dom";

const NavLink = styled(BaseNavLink)`
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0 10px;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 0.1px solid lightgrey;

  &.active {
    .... your active CSS rules here
  }
`;
```

Tested and works in both RRDv5 and RRDv6.

| RRDv5 | RRDv6 |
| --- | --- |
| [image: Edit how-to-make-activeclass-on-navlink-styled-component] | [image: Edit how-to-make-activeclass-on-navlink-styled-component (forked)] |
| "/drinks" | "/burgers" |
| [image] | [image] |

Answer (score 0):

Your code is missing some stuff, like I am not seeing anywhere you are setting  `color: red` like you want. Basically, the active link will have the class `active` applied, so either using a normal stylesheet or inside your `styled(Link`, you have to write a rule for that class that does what you want.

Like it says here [Use 'active' state from React Router in Styled Components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50208306/use-active-state-from-react-router-in-styled-components). You may have to use the `&.active` selector to apply the styles.

`activeClassName` just changes what the class name is, which isn't what you want. By default it is `active` which is fine, you just have to write the CSS rule to match it. https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/NavLink/activeclassname-string